# error: expected template-name before < token

Tags: c++, templates

Hello I am getting the following error

```
templateatt.cpp:4:32: error: expected template-name before ‘<‘ token
templateatt.cpp:4:32: error: expected â{â before ‘<‘ token
templateatt.cpp:4:32: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<‘ token
```

When I compile the following cpp file:

```
    #include<iostream>

    template <class R, class T>
    class mem_fun_t: unary_function<T*, R> {
      R (T::*pmf)();
    public:
      explicit mem_fun_t(R (T::*p)()):pmf(p){}
      R operator() (T *p) const { return (p->*pmf()); }
    };

    int main() {
      return 0;
    }
```

Any help will be great. I Am stuck at this.

Comment: The compiler and me, we both can not see any definition of `unary_function`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to `#include <functional>` to get `unary_function` and then qualify it with `std::unary_function`.

Comment: @user1663533 Good! I know you can't yet, but don't forget to accept when you can. Thanks. :)